# "git status" shows no changes, despite seeing changes in Github

Tags: git

I had some changes *X* and *Y* locally in my `feature-branch`, that I committed and pushed. After pushing, I noticed that there were new changes in `master` that I needed in `feature-branch`, so I did this:

```
git checkout master

git pull

git checkout feature-branch

git rebase master

git push -f
```

At this point, I noticed changes *X* and *Y* are no longer present in `feature-branch`, but are on my remote `feature-branch`.

`git fetch` and then `git status` shows this

`Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature-branch'`

In github, I can see this

`This branch is 2 commits ahead, 7 commits behind master.`

I assume I screwed something up with the rebase. What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this? I would like the end state to be having all 9 of the commits (X and Y from `feature-branch`, and 7 from `master`) to be in both local and remote `feature-branch`

Comment: Do you understand your situation if you open `gitk --all` locally?

Comment: I think you should show us the output of `git log --oneline --graph feature-branch origin/feature-branch master origin/master`.... at least the relevant portion of the chart.